# Jspdf generated pdf and need to attach that to email as attachment

Tags: javascript, email, pdf, jspdf

I have generated the pdf thru Jspdf and need to attach to email as attachment.

i searched option in jspdf, i didnt get options, do you have any idea on how to do this either in jquery/JS ?

-SM

Comment: You need a mail server to send email, which browsers don't have. So the short answer is to send the data of the pdf to your web server and have it send the email out in one of many different ways. If you tell us about which server language you use, the answers below my end up being more useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to encode it and put inside your email. Same technique is used to embed images.

[image]

See all the details [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1759/embedding-images-revisited/)

**Update**

Yes, the example above shows how to embed image inside an email. As I said, the same approach can be used to attach a file. For example, I have the following mail in my mailbox:

[image]

It has been attached in the following way:

[image]

I hope everything is clear till this point. Please note "Content-Disposition".

**Do you have any idea on how to do this either in jquery/JS?**

You'll need some server-side code in order to do that. I would suggest to use [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)

> A PHP email creation and transport class featuring file attachments,
>   SMTP servers, CCs, BCCs, HTML messages, word wrap, and more. Sends
>   email via sendmail, PHP mail(), QMail, or with SMTP.

Or use [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses)

> Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon SES) is a highly scalable and
>   cost-effective bulk and transactional email-sending service for
>   businesses and developers.

Please check [**SendRawEmail**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendRawEmail.html)

> Sends an email message, with header and content specified by the
>   client. The SendRawEmail action is useful for sending multipart MIME
>   emails. The raw text of the message must comply with Internet email
>   standards; otherwise, the message cannot be sent.

Should be clear right now.

Comment: The question is 'how to attach a pdf' , not 'how to embed an image' as in newsletters.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer. Technique is pretty much the same.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more query.Since JSPdf generates a PDF on the client side , how should the generated document be passed to the server script ? Is it done by POSTing the done via AJAX? If so,how ? Basically , the generated document is returned this way

`return doc.output();` . How would I post it to the server if I need to use it along with PHPMailer?

Comment: See this - http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/ and this http://ukuvuma.littledime.co.za/sending-a-ajax-mail-with-a-file-attachment-using-php-and-jquery/